# Negative lookahead preceded by .*

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

I want to select all text within `{}`, but only if there is no `\status…{}` in there.

Examples that should match:

```
\subsection{Hello}                -> "\subsection”, "Hello"
\section{Foobar}                  -> "\section", "Foobar"
\subsubsection{This is a Triumph} -> "\subsubsection", "This is a Triumph"
```

Examples that should **not** match:

```
\subsection{Hello\statusdone{}}
\section{Hello World\statuswip{}}
\section{Everything\statusproofreading{}}
```

I thought negative lookaheads would be perfect for this:

```regex
(\\.*section)\{(.*)(?!\\status.*)\}
```

but they match:

```
\subsection{Hello\statusdone{}}           -> "\subsection", "Hello\statusdone{}"
\section{Hello World\statuswip{}}         -> "\section", "Hello World\statuswip{}"
\section{Everything\statusproofreading{}} -> "\section", "Everything\statusproofreading{}"
```

I suspect it is because of the `.*` preceding the negative lookahead. If I replace it with, e.g.g, `Hello` in the following regex:

```regex
(\\.*section)\{(Hello)(?!\\status.*)\}
```

It correctly does not match the first negative example `\subsection{Hello\statusdone{}}`.

How do I work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the negative lookahead earlier in the pattern, so that it checks for the presence of that substring *before* the entire string (`.*`) is consumed.

You can use:

```
\\.*section\{((?!.*\\status.*\{\})[^}]+)}
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/HtUo2v/1).

Answer (score 1):

Regex doesn't have a needle not-inside haystack tester. (Or at least not common implementation of it.)

You're confusing the way zero-width assertions work. It's an ANY match, not an ALL match. The instant that the first position matches, that fits and it returns it.

You have a two-pass job ahead of you. First problem is that you don't have a Regular language here in LaTeX or whatever, and that means Regular Expressions aren't going to work well for arbitrary text.

`\section{\math{\ref{\status{asfd}}}}` and the final "}" you match, etc.

You need a parser to do that right, not regex. Sorry.

Comment: You are absolutely right that RegEx are not the ideal tool for processing LaTeX. But it's all VS Code offers. And it's a for a very narrow and limited use case and I'm not going to turn this into a library or anything :) I still don't quite see why .* would match the entire string if there is the negative lookahead in place: In "Hello\statusdone{}" it matches "Hello" and I could see that it would only match "Hell" because it's an ANY and not an ALL match. But why the entire string? Why can it ignore the lookahead in that case?

Comment: That ".*" doesn't have to match at a location. By adding a zero-width assertion, you are merely excluding some of the locations that the asterisk could have stopped at. The asterisk is greedy, so it scans to the end of the string first, and then starts backtracking. At every location, it looks to decide if this is an okay place to match the upcoming thing after asterisk, and you have excluded some of those locations with your next assertion.

Comment: If you make that asterisk nongreedy, it could help, but it's going to cause other problems.